# Proper way to attach a function to button in Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Note: I am developing in Qt creator 5.0

I am looking at someone else's Qt code and I am a little confused. It appears to me that there are essentially two ways to achieve the same task of attaching a function to a `QPushButton` `clicked()` signal.

The way that the tutorial on the Qt website instructs to do it is to go into the `Design` mode, right click on the `QPushButton`, click on "Go to slot..." and then write the code for the button in the created function.

In the code that I am currently looking at, they have written their own public function in the `MainWindow` class (which is the root class). Then in the `Design` mode's `Edit/signal slots` mode they are attaching(dragging) the `QPushButton` signal to the `MainWindow`, at which point they select the manually created function as the `slot`.

Is there a difference between these two methods, and is one way preferred over the other?

The main difference I have noticed is that if I follow the first method, then the slot/signal that I just created does not appear in the "Signal & Slots Editor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The main difference I have noticed is that if I follow the first
>   method, then the slot/signal that I just created does not appear in
>   the "Signal & Slots Editor".

That is because the slot in the first method is private slot of the `MainWindow` while in the second method the button sends signal to a public slot (or function in your example which is imho BAD habit to do though) of `MainWindow`. The difference is apparent I guess that the private slots are used within the class (`MainWindow` in this case) only and cannot be connected outside of it. I believe it's useful distinction for understanding the code which is why I disagree with this (stressed by me):

> With the first one, you are totally sure of what you're doing, no
>   misspelled words... **But hard to be updated if your code comes with
>   poor documentation.**

Two reasons:

1) As long as you name your slots sensibly (i.e. PushButton1_Clicked) it is pretty starightforward what it is connected to (signal `clicked()` of `PushButton1`).

3) Even if the functionality is reused elsewhere (the only reason to have it as public function imho) you would better call that function from such private slot of the button rather than connecting the button in the code directly to it treating it as a slot (which again is at least pretty confusing thing to do). Better yet having private slot for button and public slot for whatever is needed outside of MainWindow scope and the function itself as private method called by both... Or if the functionality is NOT used in signals/slots outside of MainWindow have it as public function but still call it from button's private slot rather than connecting it directly.

The reason for me to separate it like this is to separate the functionality and UI which applies especially to cases where you need the code to be reused outside of the UI elements but also if more than one element uses it. Being able to see the functionality isolated from UI makes it *easier* to update without worrying about what UI elements are connected to it. But that is just me. :-)

PS. Realted remark. Unless you specifically need the button to do something on `clicked()` I would suggest using `released()` signal instead because user could reconsider after clicking the button but with `clicked()` he would not be able to.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you recommend the first method (the one that the Qt tutorial suggests), correct?

Comment: Yes in most cases because it is clearer what is happening and where (as Samoth pointed out). However if you design everything programatically (without the From Designer) both methods become very similar but even then I would strongly recommend having public and private slots and releated functionality separate from each other.

Answer (score 0):

With the first one, you are totally sure of what you're doing, no misspelled words... But hard to be updated if your code comes with poor documentation.

With the second one, edition will be easier and, even if you don't document your code enough, it will be easy to update for anyone else.